# XSL - how to add all values with the same attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, transformation

So I have this XML code where I need to add all the values with the same id. Get the ID from Identity attribute not comparing it to like the value 10 or something.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="random.xsl"?>
<RootName>
    <RandomRootNode>
        <RandomNode>
            <Identity sid="10">abc</Identity>
            <Identity sid="20">def</Identity>
            <Identity sid="30">ghi</Identity>
        </RandomNode>
    </RandomRootNode>
    <SeriesRootNode>
        <Series>
            <Ran dustId="10">1</Ran>
            <Ran dustId="20">2</Ran>
            <Ran dustId="30">3</Ran>
        </Series>
        <Series>
            <Ran dustId="10">4</Ran>
            <Ran dustId="20">5</Ran>
            <Ran dustId="30">6</Ran>
        </Series>
        <Series>
            <Ran dustId="10">7</Ran>
            <Ran dustId="20">8</Ran>
            <Ran dustId="30">9</Ran>
        </Series>
    </SeriesRootNode>
</RootName>
```

So for this i need to display something like this

```
| ID | name | total |
|----|------|-------|
| 10 | abc  | 12    |
| 20 | def  | 15    |
| 30 | ghi  | 18    |
```

I tried doing it, but I can only get the total of all of them. So I get

```
| ID | name | total |
|----|------|-------|
| 10 | abc  | 45    |
| 20 | def  | 45    |
| 30 | ghi  | 45    |
```

How do I go about this?
I am fairly new to writing XSLT.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the XSLT you have tried please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working `random.xsl`.
Its output is as desired in the browser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Demo template -->
    <xsl:template match="/RootName/RandomRootNode/RandomNode">
      <table border="1">
        <th width="50">ID</th><th>name</th><th>total</th>
        <xsl:for-each select="Identity">
          <xsl:variable name="curID" select="@sid" />
          <tr>
            <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$curID" /></td>
            <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="text()" /></td>
            <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="sum(/RootName/SeriesRootNode/Series/Ran[@dustId=$curID]/text())" /></td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Remove not matched text nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="text()" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You really should be using a key for this.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Thanks for reminding me. Sure will do the next time.